# Looping out wordpress menu items and childrens

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
function render_links($page, $level = 0) {

    echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href=''>" . get_the_title( $page ) . "</a>";

    $children = get_pages("child_of=" . $page->id . "&parent=0");

    if (!empty($children)) {
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach ($children as $c) {
            render_links($c, $level + 1);
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }

    echo "</li>";
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach (get_pages("parent=0") as $p) {
    render_links($top_level);
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

This is my attempt to render out parent and childrens, however it is only looping out the current page title in lots of li's.

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE:

```
<?php
function render_links($page, $level = 0) {

    echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href=''>" . get_the_title( $page ) . "</a>";

    $children = get_pages("child_of=" . $page->id);

    if (!empty($children)) {
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach ($children as $c) {
            render_links($c, $level + 1);
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }

    echo "</li>";
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach (get_pages("parent=0") as $p) {
    render_links($top_level);
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

When trying this, it correctly loops out current page and then it spams the same children(even if there only is 1 children).

However it does not list the other parent pages on the website.
Look image:
https://gyazo.com/93728738fadc3c6e97ed18d20a46d273

Getting this error after it being rendered:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\yangtorp\wp-includes\cache.php on line
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php
function render_links($pge, $level = 0) {

    echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href=''>" . $pge->post_title . "</a>";

    $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

 if (!empty($children) && $level != 2) {

       echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";

   foreach ($children as $c) {
       render_links($c, $level + 1);
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}

else{
    echo "</li>";
}

}

echo "<ul id='menu-main' class='menu'>";
foreach (get_pages("parent=0") as $p) {
    render_links($p);
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

One step closer. Now it lists the parent pages, and displays the name correctly. However I cant get this to work:

```
$children = get_pages("child_of=" . $page->id . "&parent=0");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do like this :

```
 if (!empty($children)) {

       echo "<ul>";

   foreach ($children as $c) {
        render_links($c, $level + 1);
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}

 //missing else case
else{
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function render_links($pge, $level = 0) {

    echo "<li>";

    echo "<a href=''>" . $pge->post_title . "</a>";

    //set arguments for which properties and sorting order the children should get.
    $args = array( 
            'child_of' => $pge->ID, 
            'parent' => $pge->ID,
            'hierarchical' => 0,
            'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
            'sort_order' => 'asc'
    );

    // throw the arguments into the get_pages query
    $children = get_pages($args);

 if (!empty($children) && $level != 2) {

       echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";

   foreach ($children as $c) {
       render_links($c, $level + 1);
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}

else{
    echo "</li>";
}

}

echo "<ul id='menu-main' class='menu'>";
foreach (get_pages("parent=0") as $p) {
    render_links($p);
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```